# Summing the result of nested IF statements in one cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, sum, range

I've got a pretty complex conditional formula that works for each row of a column (sorry, no excel 2016 IFS) and I would like to get the sum of all instances in a range in one formula without having to make all the rows as a middle step.

Done this quite a bit with other stuff, but for some reason I'm stuck on this one.

The formula per cell is:

`=IF((IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<1),0,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<2,1,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<5,2,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<13,3,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<34,4,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<91,5,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<245,6,IF(IF(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!B2),Test_Samples!B2>0.1),Reference_Dataset!$H:$H,"")="N",Test_Samples!B2,0)<666,7,))))))))`

I would like to transform it to a formula that sums everything from the range B:B (or B2:B499) in one go.

I tried some SUM and SUMIF(S) stuff and changing B2 to B:B. That doesn't seem to work.

Oh, if someone has a tip to reduce the nested IF formula to something more readable, that's welcome as well. The idea of the formula is to transform counts to classes.

The datasets that are referred to look like this:

Test_Samples:

[image]

Reference_Dataset:

[image]

The If statements make up a classification as follows:

0= 0

1= 1

2= 2-4

3= 5-12

4= 13-33

5= 34-90

6= 91-244

7= 245-665

8= 666+

Here you see a count of 2 in "Test_samples", and it is labelled "N" in "Reference_dataset", so the result classifies it as "2" (to avoid confusion: if the count was 5 it would be labelled "3" according to the class criteria). 
Say if there are 5 instances with result "2" in the range B2:B499, the sum should be 10.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and the expected output?

Comment: yep, a sample would help to understand your needs

Comment: *Say if there are 5 instances with result "2" in the range B2:B499, the sum should be 10.* So you just want to count how many times value `2` appears in B? what about using a COUNTIF and then multiply the result by 2?

Comment: What is the conditional criteria?

Comment: Are you familiar with `SUMPRODUCT` or Array Formula?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns "(to avoid confusion: if the count was 5 it would be labelled "3" according to the class criteria)" The counts are classified: 1=1, 2-4=2, 5-12=3, 13-33=4 etc.

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre Is `Test_Samples!B182` on the third line correct? All of the other lines are `Test_Samples!B2`?

Comment: @xidgel Typo, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lookup table like this for your "result value < X" to summarize the If statements into a single lookup table:

```
Test_Samples B Value
0
1
2
5
13
34
91
245
666
```

In this example, i've put that on the same worksheet that the formula is placed, in cells A1:A10 (header in A1, so data values in A2:A10).  Then you can simplify your formula and make it reference the range of your data like this:

```
=SUM(MATCH(IF(ISNUMBER(Test_Samples!$B$2:$B$499)*(Reference_Dataset!$H$2:$H$499="N"),Test_Samples!$B$2:$B$499,0),$A$2:$A$10)-1)
```

Note that this is an array formula and as such must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: This makes me realize I might have approached the problem wrong from the beginning. Was tunneling on cramming everything into a one-size-fits-all formula and embedding classification in there. When dealing with huge data sets this is also more processor-friendly right? Thanks a bunch!